# Vb.net return multiple values from function

Tags: vb.net, function

Hi currently i have 2 functions that look like this:

```
 Function getTrigPoint(ByVal trigP As String) AS String
     Dim triG$ = Nothing
     If trigP = "This" Then triG = "Off"
     Return triG
 End Function

 Function getHexPoint(ByVal hexP As String) AS Integer
     Dim hexX% = Nothing
     If hexP= "This" Then hexX= 0
     Return hexX
 End Function
```

I was wondering if there was a way to check for either value? Like calling it like this? Like if i were to combine them into one function?

```
 getFunction(, getHexPoint)
```

The reason I am asking is because the value that each function is literally the same, and I am trying to reduce redundancy in my pet project.

Comment: Why not create a class to store/manage the data.  One is an int, the other string (?) so a simple utility class would do.

Comment: thats a good question - i never thought of it.